# run command in script after an ssh

Tags: ssh, awk, tail, sshpass

In my script I need to access a remote server using ssh. On the remote I want to gather some data from log files. I have my script set up and the code works, but my problem is when I run the script it will get to the ssh and log onto the remote server, but it wont run the next command. It waits for a keyboard input but i need the command to run without an input from the keyboard.

This is what i have.

```
 value = `sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh $USERNAME@$REMOTE_IP_ADDR | tail -F /tmp/file.txt | awk '{ print $16 }'`

//i have tested this line of code and it works how i need it to
 tail -F /tmp/file.txt | awk '{ print $16 }'
```

Comment: Try to remove the pipe between ADDR and tail and don't forget to read the man pages of ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was the pipe between the ADDR | tail

```
//old code
     value = `sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh $USERNAME@$REMOTE_IP_ADDR | tail -F /tmp/file.txt | awk '{ print $16 }'`

//edited code (working)
 value = `sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh $USERNAME@$REMOTE_IP_ADDR tail -F /tmp/file.txt | awk '{ print $16 }'
```

Thanks for the help ctac_